# Domain names mirroring my domain except for small details

Tags: domains, html, cpanel

I am just an amateur web editor and have had a **non-commercial** personal website `www.mysurname.example` with useful technical tips and culture content since 1999. I code my web pages directly in HTML and use a cheap **web hosting service with cPanel**.

Recently I have noticed that other domain names with funny names like `www.abeautytips.example` and `www.ketorecipeideas.example` are pointing to my website. These are probably **not complete copies**, because as soon as I change something on `www.mysurname.example`, the changes are immediately visible there as well.

Sometimes, however, there is an automatic change, *e.g.* `<a href="mailto:myname@mysurname.example">` is changed to `<a href="/cdn-cgi/l/email-protection#afc2ceddc4c0efdfc6c1dbcaddc6cc81ccc0c2">`, which, strangely enough, does not change the address.  This indicates that these pages are actually **piping my website** in real time.

**How dangerous is this and what can I do about it?** Please note that I am a complete amateur, have no access to Linux and my webmaster capabilities are limited by the cPanel menus.

I also wonder why is this happening. My website is not important and does not have much traffic (according to my PHP counter, maybe a few dozen page views per day, and many of those are just web spiders; according to cPanel, 5 GB of web traffic per month, including webmail).  I also found, using the [Wayback Machine - Internet Archive](https://archive.org), that copycat webpages used to exist as real webpages.

Comment: See also: [Google indexed my home page with a completely wrong domain](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/116410/google-indexed-my-home-page-with-a-completely-wrong-domain)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a couple things you can do about it:

1. Add [canonical tags](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/consolidate-duplicate-urls#rel-canonical-link-method) to every page on your site. For example one of the pages on your site should have this tag in the `<head>` section:

   ```html
   <link rel=canonical href=https://www.mysurname.example/mped.html>
   ```

   Doing this will let Google know which is the correct URL to index, even when it finds the same content on other domains.
2. Add code to your `.htaccess` file to redirect any of these alternate domains to your domain name:

   ```sh
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mysurname\.example$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mysurname.example/$1 [R=301,L]
   ```

   That way if somebody requests an alternate domain name from your web host's server, the server will issue a redirect rather than serve the content for your site.

This kind of problem is usually caused by other people accidentally pointing their domain to your web server via DNS and your web server being configured to serve your site as the "default".   When you are on cheap shared hosting, it is very unusual to have your site configured as the default, but it can happen.   In Apache's configuration, whatever site comes first in the configuration is the default.  Most hosting companies make sure that their own site is first, or that a dummy site that shows an error is first.  It is possible that your site is listed first by your hosting company.

As far as the [changed email links, that is done by Cloudflare](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170016-What-is-Email-Address-Obfuscation-). If I visit that `/cdn-cgi/l/email-protection` URL on one of the other domain names, I see a message from Cloudflare explaining that they are trying to obfuscate email addresses.   Cloudflare is a content delivery network (CDN) that uses servers all over the globe to proxy and cache websites that are configured to use it. Sites choose to use a CDN because it makes their web site faster.  The reverse proxy has Cloudflare act like a pipe between your server and the visitor, so they can (and do) alter the pages a bit in some cases.  Some of these alternate domains are set up to use Cloudflare where their DNS points to Cloudflare and then Cloudflare is configured to use your server as its "origin server."  It is likely that if you were to redirect to your domain with .htaccess, Cloudflare would also redirect these sites.

If redirects don't stop the sites that are mirroring your site through Cloudflare, you could take more drastic action and block all requests from Cloudflare completely.  Doing so would preclude you from using their services yourself.  [Cloudflare sends several headers when requesting content from your site](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170986-How-does-Cloudflare-handle-HTTP-Request-headers-) and you could configure your site to block requests if these headers are present. I picked one to use:

```sh
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-RAY} .
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: Yeah, that `.htaccess` solution is awesome! It also takes care of the Google canonical problem. I already use `.htaccess` to redirect http to https and some similar things. I should have come up with this solution myself, but it was still interesting to learn the causes of the problem.

Comment: "pointing their domain to your web server via DNS and your web server being configured to serve your site as the "default"." - Although that doesn't appear to be the case in this instance? Requesting the IP address or pointing an arbitrary domain at that IP address just results in the generic cPanel "sorry!" page. However, unless that was the case then I can't see how the `.htaccess` solution would have worked?! (Maybe there's some kind of misconfiguration at the host?? Although those other domains do seem quite spammy IMO and are registered in two different countries AFAICT?)

Comment: @MrWhite I added a paragraph about blocking Cloudflare.   Can you check the `RewriteRule` I propose? I didn't test it and you can spot problems with them for miles away.

Comment: It looks fine, although you could simplify/optimise the regex a bit, eg. `RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-RAY} .` `RewriteRule ^ - [F]` - The header just needs to contain at least 1 char (you don't need to actually match the whole header) and the `RewriteRule` just needs to be successful for everything (it doesn't need to actually match anything). Minor point, but I would remove the `NC` flag on the first condition on point #2 at the top. Since it's a _negated_ condition, you want the condition to be successful when the host is not `www.mysurname.example` (exactly, all lowercase).

Comment: @MrWhite domain names are not case sensitive.   I don't believe you should try to redirect to canonicalize the case in the domain name itself.   I believe it is correct to allow upper case letters in the domain name portion of a URL.

Comment: I've had to fix a redirect on my site because the regex I used was case sensitive. Some client insisted on upper casing the domain and got stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Yes, the domain should be _compared_ case-insensitively. However, the case is preserved in the `Host` header. So it depends on what you are doing in the rest of the application as to whether this will have an impact. eg. If you are rewriting the request to a subdirectory matching the requested host then this will likely fail (unless you are on Windows). Or performing some logic on the requested host in the application you need to ensure you are always using a case-insensitive comparison or canonicalise the host later.

Comment: @OskarSkog If you try to uppercase the domain then yes you will certainly get a redirect loop since the _browser_ lowercases the hostname before making the request. Mixed case/uppercase host headers only apply to bots. Whether you _need_ to canonicalise the host header is dependent on how your application handles it. Note that in this particular rule, the condition is _negated_. The `NC` flag should always be used on +ve hostname matches.

Comment: I have several other redirects in my .htaccess (removing index.html and multiple slashes, enforcing www. and https). None uses [NC]. To be consistent with your solution, should I add [NC] elsewhere as well?

Comment: @MrWhite I assume you figured out which two domain names mirror my domain name. Do you have another explanation for what's going on? I think this mirroring is probably unintentional as my domain name has little traffic and is of little importance. Why would anyone bother to interfere with a site like this?

Comment: @Pygmalion "should I add [NC] elsewhere as well" - It depends on the specific rules - ask another question! :) But... "probably". However, overuse of the `NC` flag can itself cause problems (and it is overused). "removing index.html" - can use `NC`, but probably makes no difference, since `INDEX.HTML` is unlikely to be accessible anyway (unless you are on Windows - unlikely).

Answer (score 4):

It isn't dangerous.  Looking at DNS, both those domains are hosted through cloudflare, so it likely a misconfiguration there.

If it bothers you it is possible to stop them displaying your content.  Here is a technical answer https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/83362/how-can-i-stop-someone-from-displaying-my-website-on-his-domain  You could ask the hosting service to help.

Or...you could place some ads on the site and possibly benefit from it ;o)

Comment: Thanks for the reply - that was a great relief to me. The only problem is that the **stupid** Google gets confused and sometimes thinks that these piping domain names are real domain names. As for monetization, I occasionally get offers to run ads - which is pretty silly; with the current traffic on my site, I'd make maybe a few cents a month - it's not worth it. So I am wondering why I am receiving these offers in the first place.

Comment: I read the link you suggested. I can barely understand anything. First, can you please tell me if I can even do this on cPanel?

Comment: @Pygmalion "You could ask the hosting service to help."